# Prevent line break in textarea with JavaScript - how to?

Tags: javascript, onclick, key

When i click on "enter" I call a function. Within this function I do the following:

```
  var key = event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13 && !event.shiftKey)
```

I am using this function on a textarea.

When I press enter everything works except one thing: A line break is made within the textarea which should be prevented. How to avoid?

Comment: event.preventDefault?

Comment: Hi , where i can use event.preventDefault?

Comment: Oh it's works !!! Thanks you ! I use that in the end of my function js

Comment: Use it at the beginning, makes more logical sense

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it:

```
function(event) {  
  event.preventDefault();  
  var key = event.keyCode;
  if (key == 13 && !event.shiftKey) ...
}
```

event.preventDefault() also works for links and in any other case you want to prevent the default action of an event.

Another important function sometimes is `event.stopPropagation()`.

More information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Thanks you for your help ;)